# Is AJAX success callback synchronous?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I know that AJAX is asynchronous. But what about the event execution inside the success callback? For example, if I have code like

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'example.com',
    type: 'GET',
    success : (dataFromServer) {
        event1();
        event2();
        event3();  
    }
})
```

Will they execute in order? Assuming event1(), event2(), and event3() are synchronous functions

Comment: Have you tried `javascript` at Question?

Comment: Or you can set async:false

Comment: @AsifRaza no you can't. It's deprecated as of JQuery 1.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they'll be executed one after the other

Comment: Because `success` callback is just a regular js function, nothing special going on.